# Django post save signal not updating the database

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-signals

Im not getting why this signal is not working. This same code worked once but after that i deleted the objects from admin and ran it again and it stopped working.

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=FinancePending)
def calcualate_FinancePending(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
amount_paid = FinancePending.objects.values_list('amountPaid', flat=True)
amount_paid = list(amount_paid)
total_amount = FinancePending.objects.values_list('TotalAmount', flat=True)
total_amount = list(total_amount)

# total - paid
TotalFee = [int(s.replace(',', '')) for s in total_amount]
AmountPaid = [int(s.replace(',', '')) for s in amount_paid]
finance_pending = FinancePending.objects.all()
i = 1

while i <= len(TotalFee):
    amount_pending = TotalFee[i-1] - AmountPaid[i-1]
    amountpending = FinancePending.objects.filter(invoiceNumber=i)
    amountpending.AmountPending = amount_pending
    i = 1 + i
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not call `save()` method, that is why it is not saving. But I do not think it is a optimized implementation from django's prespective. You can simply try like this using [`update()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once):

```
from django.db.models import F

@receiver(post_save, sender=FinancePending)
def calcualate_FinancePending(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    FinancePending.objects.update(AmountPending=F('TotalAmount')-F('amountPaid'))
```

Also, it does not make sense to update each and every object one instance of `FinancePending` is created. Probably you should only update the object which was created. Like this:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=FinancePending)
def calcualate_FinancePending(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    instance.AmountPending=instance.TotalAmount-instance.amountPaid
    instance.save()
```

Finally, please follow [pep8 style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) when naming your attributes and function names.

Comment: The issue is that im importing bulk data from csv. In which the pending coloumns are empty.

Answer (score 0):

Because signal [post_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/signals/#post-save) only triggered after call save() method. You should use [post_delete](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/signals/#post-delete) instead.